# How to process less than symbols inside text in BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: xml, beautifulsoup

I have a line like

`<charseq START="98" END="139">Low Insulation Resistance (<10 Megohms): 0</charseq>`

in part of my data which is in xml format.  I use the lxml-xml parser.  The <10 is meant to be a mathematical expression obviously and not a begin tag for xml.

So when I do the following code:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml-xml'/)`

the document is not processed correctly and the xml data is truncated abruptly at this point.  Do I have to manually escape the data myself or is there some argument to pass to BeautifulSoup to handle such cases?

I am expecting a legal xml document in soup such that I can use `find()` to access various parts of the document